# How to suppress 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData' should not be used to for un-archiving and will be removed in a future release` from Xcode console

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, console, ios14

When I build and run my iOS application(`MyApp`) in my iPhone(**iOS 14**), the below line is printing in the Xcode(**11.7**) console so many times within a seconds.

```
2020-10-27 10:18:37.207983+0600 MyApp[5164:2375439] [general] 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData' should not be used to for un-archiving and will be removed in a future release
```

The frequent print of this log making some issue like

- Freeze the UI of my application(Sometimes)
- Making the size of my application Log file bigger
- Making the xcode console so annoying

Is there any way to suppress this log from xcode console when debugging?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about to refactor the code to *suppress* the usage of the API

Comment: Is there are any way to suppress that log without modifying internal code, it would be better for me. I have less knowledge about the code and the app is too big!!